# jQuery: how to get new value, but not old value at on('save') event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, save

I using X-editable and  try to catch the value of element when user changed it, but I can't catch the changed value, always got the previous one.

ex: original value is 'a', 1st time:change it to 'b' but got 'a'. 2nd time change it to 'c' but got 'b'.

I using save event because change event is not work.

page.blade.php

```
<a class='editable' href="#" name='id' data-pk='{{$item->id}}'>{{$item->id}}</a></th>
```

script

```
$('.editable').on('save', function(e){
                       console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-pk')+' '+e.target.text+' '+e.target.getAttribute('name'));});
```

Comment: Which event handles the click on the _a_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A div will never trigger a `change` event, as that's reserved for inputs the user can manipulate.

If you still want to listen to changes made to the inner HTML of a div, you can try the following, while that may not work in Internet Explorer or older browsers at all:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.editable').on('DOMSubtreeModified'), function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-pk')+' '+e.target.text+' '+e.target.getAttribute('name'));});
    }
}
```

Be careful not to overwrite the div's content inside the event handler, or you will cause an infinite loop. I suggest expanding your knowledge on the `DOMSubtreeModified` event by reading, for example, the MDN article: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: thx, I review the document that u give, and triggered DOMNodeInserted to solved it.